# Add push array with vuejs composition api with typescript - I want to be able to add multiple invoices in your form

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a form and I have a field invoice field, in this field I can have 1 or more invoices, if it is more than one invoice, it will generate an array of values, follow an image below trying to pass the values, and it returns an object inside of an array.

I'm using vuejs with composition api and typescript., can you help me, please?.

[image]

SCRIPT VUEJS

```html
<template>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="addRow">+</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="removeRow">-</button>
        <div v-for="item in formNotaFiscal" :key="item">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label" for="key_number">Chave </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="key_number" maxlength="44" placeholder="Chave"
                    v-model="formNotaFiscal" required />
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, onMounted, reactive, watch, ref } from 'vue'
import useDocument from '@/composables/documents';
import Multiselect from '@vueform/multiselect/src/Multiselect';
import ModalPersonCreate from '@/components/Modal/ModalPersonCreate.vue';

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'MovimentCreate',
    components: {
        Multiselect,
        ModalPersonCreate
    },
    setup(){

        const { documents, getDocuments, fetchDocuments, storeDocument}                      = useDocument();
        const { storeCartMoviment}                                                           = useCartMoviments();
        const { errors, currentDate, storeMoviment}                                          = useMoviment();
      
        const formNotaFiscal  = reactive({
            key_number: []
        });
        
        const addRow = () => {
            formNotaFiscal.key_number.push()
        }

         const removeRow = (index) => {
             if(formNotaFiscal.length > 1)
                 formNotaFiscal.splice(index,1)
         }

        watch(() => formDocumentType.document_type_id, (valueAtual) => {
            formMoviment.document_type_id = valueAtual
        })

        const salvarMoviment = async () => {
            await storeMoviment({...formMoviment});
            await storeCartMoviment({...formCartMoviment});
            await storeDocument({...formNotaFiscal, key_number: [] });
        }
        
        onMounted(() => {
            getDocuments();
        })

        return{
            formMoviment,
            formCartMoviment,
            formDocumentType,
            formNotaFiscal,
            addRow,
            id,
            // key_number,
            // listItems,
            // removeRow,
            vehicles,
            companies,
            persons,
            documents,
            departments,
            documentTypes,
            salvarMoviment,
            currentDate,
            fetchVehicles,
            fetchCompany,
            fetchPerson,
            fetchDocuments,
            errors
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: No one understand what you're writing about. Edit your question, please, so people can understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Dear,

I have a form and I have a field invoice field, in this field I can have 1 or more invoices, if it is more than one invoice, it will generate an array of values, follow an image below trying to pass the values, and it returns an object inside of an array.

I'm using vuejs with composition api and typescript.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to achieve. Paste full code of your `someComponent.vue` file.

Comment: You want to be able to add multiple invoices in your form?

Comment: @Mises Yes, add multiple rows invoices my forms, thanks, code updated on post, thank tou very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can make form with array.

```js
<template>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="addRow">+</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="showArray">Show Array</button>
        <div v-for="(item, index) in formNotaFiscal.key_number" :key="index">
            <div class="mb-3 flex gap-2">
                <label class="form-label" for="key_number">Chave </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="key_number" maxlength="44" placeholder="Chave"
                    v-model="item.title" required />
                <br>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="removeRow(index)">-</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

const formNotaFiscal = reactive({ key_number: [] });

const addRow = () => {
    formNotaFiscal.key_number.push({ title: 'New title'})
}

const showArray = () => {
    console.log(formNotaFiscal.key_number)
}

const removeRow = (index) => {
    formNotaFiscal.key_number.splice(index,1)
}
</script>
```

With setup out of `<script>`.

```js
setup(){
   const formNotaFiscal = reactive({ key_number: [] });

   const addRow = () => {
      formNotaFiscal.key_number.push({ title: 'New title'})
   }

   const showArray = () => {
      console.log(formNotaFiscal.key_number)
   }

   const removeRow = (index) => {
      formNotaFiscal.key_number.splice(index,1)
   }
   return {formNotaFiscal, removeRow, showArray, addRow}
}
```

**Edit**

```js
const formNotaFiscal = reactive<{key_number: any[]}>({ key_number: [] });
```

You can assign type as above or configure tsconfig.json file.

Comment: Hello good morning @Mises!

Thank you very much for your time, I'm getting the following error when trying to do it with your help.

Comment: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'. formNotaFiscal.key_number.push({ title: "New Title" });`

Comment: Thank you very much @Mises, Forgive me for my ignorance, I'm studying to one day be able to be a programmer with the same talent.

Have a good day!